Treat value inside quotes as one collective value
This is the code for my project, with self.keywords being a list containing keywords

escaped_keywords = list(map(re.escape, self.keywords))

joined_keywords = '|'.join(escaped_keywords)

pattern = rf"\\b({joined_keywords})\\b|(\[^\\w\\s\])"

temp = re.split(pattern, line)

In the pattern variable, lies well, the pattern. Now I need a pattern to treat everything within " and ' as a string, meaning even if symbols show up within the string, like this one: "hello, world!", it won't split the , and !.
The pattern right now, if fed  "hello, world!" it would return:
'"', 'hello', ',', 'world', '!', '"'
While the desired output would be:
'"', 'hello, world!', '"'
I tried this: "(.?)"|\'(.?)\' I tried to match the quoted string, but I have no idea what I'm doing since I used a regex playground to experiment. This did work though, capturing the " and ' but, who,e doing so, it also captured all the symbols inside of the string:
"Hello, World!" from this, it captured all instances of: ", , and ! which I don't want, since the pattern is supposed to ignore the things within the strings, including ' and every other symbol.

You want to do re.split() on your pattern but have single- or double- quotes treated as regular non-whitespace characters, so it doesn't split on them. In that case you can't have something as expansive as ([\w\s]) in your pattern, you'd need to list out every single \w non-whitespace character where you do want to split, which would be a pain (e.g. only split not on \s whitespace but only on punctuation characters which exclude ' and  So let's rethink your approach: better to split the line only on " quotes, then avoid splitting further on subexpressions inside the quotes.

But your example is not complete or reproducible ("MCVE", [mcve]), since we don't know your list escaped_keywords, please edit the question to add it. Otherwise noone here can run your code.

In general, regular expressions are not good at distinguishing "inside" from "outside". You should probably be using a real CSV parser.

One easy way might be to turn the string into a byte-stream and read it with a CSV reader. That'll handle the quote-escaping. Then apply your regex to the result

It should be pattern = rf"\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*'|\b(?:{joined_keywords})\b|[^\w\s]|_)"
